# How do I know if phantom power is on or off?

Tags: phantom, power

I have the +48V push rectangle on my small Behringer 602A. How do I know if the phantom power is on or off?  Is it on when the light is red and button is pushed in?   I am starting with a condenser mic with the button out. I engage mic, then push in button. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you're correct - the red light means on.

And best practice dictates connecting the mic first, then turning on phantom power.

Answer (score 0):

Mic in, power on (light comes on).

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me and have Ribbon mics and are terrified of frying that $1,200 mic by plugging it into a cable,

you can purchase these:

http://www.google.com/products/catalog?client=safari&rls=en&q=phantom+power+tester&oe=UTF-8&safe=vss&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=7275317222120391040&sa=X&ei=U5hrT9aMCo_QiAK_1si6BQ&ved=0CE8Q8wIwAA#ps-sellers

It shows if there is phantom power coming down the line.

I have one that shows if the phantom power is on the right pin or not (wrongly wired pins can fry ribbons).